# ListView in subwindow triggers immediate close, or whilst scrolling

Tags: qt, debugging, qml, qt-quick

I have rather strange scenario whereby if I launch a subwindow that contains a `ListView` with a moderately complex delegate and enough items to comfortably exceed the visible area, the entire subwindow will immediately close on launch.

Reducing the complexity of the delegate will allow the window to open, but then rapidly scrolling the `ListView` will forcibly close it.

This [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) triggers the effect on my laptop, but on a more powerful machine it may only do it whilst scrolling (or perhaps the delegate may need to be more complex):

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 200

    Component.onCompleted: {
        win.createObject( null );
    }

    Component {
        id: win

        Window {
            width: 600
            height: 400

            visible: true

            ListView {
                id: view
                anchors.fill: parent

                model: 100

                boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
                clip: true

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: view.width
                    height: 24

                    property int debugLevel: index % 3
                    property int timestamp: index * 1000
                    property int message: index

                    color: "darkgray"

                    Row {
                        anchors.fill: parent

                        Repeater {
                            id: delegateRepeater

                            property list< QtObject > roleModel: [
                                QtObject {
                                    property string label: timestamp
                                    property int itemWidth: 100
                                },
                                QtObject {
                                    property string label: debugLevel
                                    property int itemWidth: 100
                                },
                                QtObject {
                                    property string label: message
                                    property int itemWidth: view.width - 100 - 100
                                }
                            ]

                            model: roleModel

                            Item {
                                width: itemWidth
                                anchors {
                                    top: parent.top
                                    bottom: parent.bottom
                                }

                                Text {
                                    anchors {
                                        fill: parent
                                        leftMargin: 4
                                    }

                                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

                                    text: label
                                    elide: Text.ElideRight
                                }

                                Rectangle {
                                    anchors {
                                        top: parent.top
                                        bottom: parent.bottom
                                        right: parent.right
                                    }

                                    width: 1

                                    visible: index != ( delegateRepeater.count - 1 )
                                    color: "white";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any particular part of the code that is causing the problem, removing *any* of the objects in the delegate reduces the probability of the subwindow closing.

I've added the debugging tag because my main problem is that this effect *produces no debug output*.  If I add a breakpoint into the subwindow's destruction handler (`Component.onDestruction`) then there is a single stack entry pointing at the `model: roleModel` statement - but removing the entire `Repeater` and replacing with a copy-and-pasted equivalent yields the same results minus the stack entry.

So I would be grateful is anyone knows of a way of getting more information from this pure QML example.

Comment: `win.createObject( null );` creates a window without parent, so the QML engine delete/close this window when resource-releasing is triggered. Try `Window { id: root; Component.onCompleted: { win.createObject( root ); } /*...*/ }`.

Comment: @mcchu This is not a solution because the created window's lifetime now depends on the lifetime of the parent - which fundamentally changes the applications behaviour.

Comment: @cmannett85 I'm not fully sure what you were trying to accomplish here 4 years ago. But reading it now, I think what you could do instead of manually managing multiple Window objects is using StackView or a TabView or even a SwipeView. Depending on your use case, if you need two "Windows" on Android, even having two Items/Rectangles/Panes with your content filling the root window and making the one or the other visible, or (un)loading the one or the other with a Loader could be a solution. Maybe even simply using a Dialog could be what you want, these work pretty well on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @BaCaRoZzo the changing of behaviour by modifying the delegate code seems to be an unrelated side-issue.

The real cause is because it turns out you [cannot create new root contexts](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_project_org_faq#How_can_I_create_multiple_toplevel_windows_in_QML.3F) (i.e. top-level windows) from QML.  This was hinted at being resolved when Qt Quick Components were released, but the [blog post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/08/26/toplevel-windows-and-menus-with-qt-quick/) boasting of `Window` doesn't explicitly state this.  Creating a new `Window` and passing `null` for the parent *technically* works but the result seems to be very unstable.

Thankfully in my circumstance I'm creating a QML/C++ application so I've solved the issue by creating new root contexts from `Q_INVOKABLE` methods on the C++ side.  But if you're developing a pure QML application, it seems that you are out of luck.

Comment: I still deleted the answer as the point was in studying *that* particular case. My apologize in not getting the point straight. That's it indeed and it is confirmed by a little modification of your original code: if you set an `id` in the parent `Window` and pass it to the `createObject` the code works perfectly (hence using the context of outer `Window`). IMO it is of interest [this part of the documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#creating-a-component-dynamically) about `createObject`.