# How to open a second ApplicationWindow on android qml

Tags: android, qt, qml

I have two application windows and I want to open a second one like so in the attached code.

I have a couple of questions:
1. by opening a second window would this create the equivalent to an android "Activity"?

2. if i pressed the back button would it return to the previous application window? Like an android activity?
3. if 2 is false then which is the best practice for this?

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id:window
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true


    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill:parent
        color:"blue"
    }

    Rectangle{
        width:parent.width/6
        height:width/3
        anchors.centerIn:parent

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill:parent
            onClicked:{
                var component = Qt.createComponent("Two.qml");
                if (component.status == Component.Ready)
                     component.createObject(window, {});
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Two.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id:window
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill:parent
        color:"red"
    }
}
```

When I click on the rectangle to open the second window i get the following error:

```
W/Adreno-EGL(25103): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3556>: EGL_BAD_CONTEXT
W/Qt      (25103): (null):0 ((null)): QEGLPlatformContext::swapBuffers(): eglError: 12294, this: 0x6234de38
```

Comment: Most probably related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556908/listview-in-subwindow-triggers-immediate-close-or-whilst-scrolling). See [this blogpost](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/07/23/anatomy-of-a-qt-5-for-android-application/) to understand the correlation between Qt and Android).

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response. I flipped through the blog and will read in more detail but as far as the related qu i tried all the code and it still does the same thing.